# Does the look of your equipped armor effect how NPCs react to you?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I just began the Game of Thrones video game and came upon an early Wildling boss that dropped a good suit of armor. However, the armor happens to have severed human heads hanging off it and human ears stitched to the front. In the "civilized" areas of Westeros I'd imagine this would be frowned upon. Does the appearance of the armor effect how NPCs will treat my character?

[image: Armor of severed heads]

Comment: Wow...that is so badass XD